# Phillips-Labs terraform-aws-github-runner not creating ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, terraform, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am trying to set up self-hosted runners for GitHub using Terraform with Phillips-Labs `terraform-aws-github-runner` module. I see the GH webhook send/receive messages, SQS queue receiving messages and those messages being retrieve. The scale-up lambda is firing and I see the following logs:

```
2023-01-31 11:50:15.879  INFO  [scale-up:22b11002-76d2-5596-9451-4c51746730c2 index.js:119051  scaleUp] Received workflow_job from {my-org}/terraform-aws-github-self-hosted-runners 
{}

2023-01-31 11:50:15.880  INFO  [scale-up:22b11002-76d2-5596-9451-4c51746730c2 index.js:119084  scaleUp] Received event 
{
    "runnerType": "Org",
    "runnerOwner": "my-org",
    "event": "workflow_job",
    "id": "11002102910"
}
  
2023-01-31 11:50:16.188 DEBUG [gh-auth:22b11002-76d2-5596-9451-4c51746730c2 index.js:118486 createAuth] GHES API URL: {"runnerType":"Org","runnerOwner":"my-org","event":"workflow_job","id":"11002102910"}

2023-01-31 11:50:16.193  WARN [scale-runners:22b11002-76d2-5596-9451-4c51746730c2 index.js:118529  Runtime.handler] Ignoring error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported 
{
    "runnerType": "Org",
    "runnerOwner": "my-org",
    "event": "workflow_job",
    "id": "11002102910"
}
```

I do not see any EC2 instances being creating. I suspect the `GHES API URL:` *should* have a value after it, but I'm not certain. Also, the final log says it is ignoring an error...

I have confirmed my private key pem file is stored as a multi-line secret in secrets manager.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not all the permissions needed by the github app are documented. I needed to add a subscription to the `Workflow run` event.